# Line plot legend does not appear

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line, legend

I am trying to plot a line plot in r by using ggplot. Unfortunately, the legend does not show up. Can anyone help me?

My code looks like the following:

```
dfdatavgsM=data.frame(datum, avgsätzegespMT, avgsätzegespML)
 ggplot(data = dfdatavgsM, aes(x=datum, color=Wettbewerbsart))
+ geom_line(data=dfdatavgsM, aes(y = avgsätzegespML),color="red")
+ geom_line(data=dfdatavgsM, aes(y = avgsätzegespMT), color="blue")
+ geom_vline(xintercept=2011, size = 0.6)
+ scale_y_continuous(name="Anzahl an Sätzen")
+ scale_x_datetime(name = "Saison" ,date_breaks = ("2 year"),date_labels = "%Y") 
+ ggtitle("Wettbewerbsintensität in Spielen mit |∆TTR| ≤ 118") + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black")) 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', colour = "light grey")) + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1))
```

Comment: The legend will only appear if you use `color` inside an `aes` statement. You will need to reshape your data to 'long' format (see `tidyr::gather`), and have a single `geom_line` term and an `aes` including `color=type` where `type` is the variable indicating `av..ML` or `av..MT`.

Comment: when I put it into long format, I get a list with the data in the first columns and the av..ML an av..MT in the following columns. I can't imagine how the plot can then show the relationship between the data and the av..ML.

Comment: I also got the problem, that if I write the "color=" into the aes(), I get the warning "there is no package named ´digest´"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend will only appear if you use `color` inside an `aes` statement. You will need to reshape your data to 'long' format (e.g. with `tidyr::gather`), and have a single `geom_line` term and an `aes` including `color=type`.  Something like this (not tested as I don't have your data)...

```
library(tidyverse)

dfdatavgsM=data.frame(datum, avgsätzegespMT, avgsätzegespML)

dfdatavgsMlong <- dfdatavgsM %>% gather(key = type, value = value, -datum)

ggplot(data = dfdatavgsMlong, aes(x=datum, y=value, color=type)) + 
   geom_line()
```

Comment: Now another question.. R sets the color of the lines automatically. How can I change them manually?

Comment: You can do that in a `scale_color_manual` statement added to your ggplot.

Comment: thanks a lot! I´m sorry, I am an absolute beginner in R :D